# How to simplify numpy conditional statements to find neighbouring indices of elements given a value?

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, array-broadcasting

How to simplify conditional statement in numpy array to find neighbouring indices of all list elements V given search list bins. For example, if bins is a list of 100 elements ranging from 1.1 to 100.1, V is a list of [23,77.4,42].  The task is for each element in V, find its neighbouring indices in bins. Currently code below requires to compare two vectors 4 times and then add where results to true to the output lists.  How to simplify this task?

```
def testFindBoundaryVector():

    bins = np.linspace(start=1.1, stop=100.1, num=100)
    V = np.array([23, 77.4, 42])
    V_T = np.reshape(V, (V.shape[0], 1))
    # broadcasting 
    Diff = np.abs(bins - V_T)
    Index = np.argmin(Diff, axis=1)

    print(f"indices: {Index}")
    print(f"value: {bins[Index]}")
    print(f"shape of Diff: {Diff.shape}")

    left, right = [], []

    LeftIndex = Index[V >= bins[Index]]
    RightIndex = LeftIndex + 1

    left.extend(LeftIndex)
    right.extend(RightIndex)

    LeftIndex = Index[V < bins[Index]] - 1
    RightIndex = LeftIndex + 1

    left.extend(LeftIndex)
    right.extend(RightIndex)

    print(f"left Index: {left}")
    print(f"right Index: {right}")
    return
```

Expected Result:
Left = [21,76,40]
Right = [22,77,41]

Comment: `RightIndex = LeftIndex + 1`

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for the comment. It did same some comparisons. Originally I intended to solve it with numpy where method but could not figure it out how to handle it in multiple statements. Any more suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
import numpy as np
L = np.linspace(1.1, 100.1, 100)
V = np.array([23,77.4,42])
Right = np.argmin(L[:,None]<V[None,:],axis=0)
Left = Right - 1
```

Comment: it is a very nice solution. The only difference is that if the input value is out of boundary, such as V = [-1,105], Left = [-1，-1], Right = [0，0], while my original solution gives Left = [-1,99], Right =[0,100], which can tell the difference of two inputs.

Comment: I see. What about using `Right = np.sum(L[:,None]<W[None,:],axis=0)` instead?